# Cycle 2 Stacked Carousel

Tags: jquery, css, carousel, jquery-cycle2

I have a Cycle 2 Carousel something like the second example down on the Cycle 2 carousel page: **[here](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/carousel.php)**

The slides are six side by side:

< [ 1 ] [ 2 ] [ 3 ] [ 4 ] [ 5 ] [ 6 ] >

What I want is to set them up in a grid like this:

[ 1 ] [ 2 ] [ 3 ]

[ 4 ] [ 5 ] [ 6 ]

With the arrows centered on either side. Any way to do this or is this unfeasible?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, by grouping images by 2 and styling them vertically.
Make a non image slide ex <div> with 2 images inside, cycle will treat it as 1 slide. Added example in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by grouping your slides by 2.

```
<div class="slideshow" 
    data-cycle-fx=carousel
    data-cycle-timeout=1000
    data-cycle-carousel-visible=5
    data-cycle-slides="> div"
    >
    <div class="2-images">
       <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach1.jpg">
       <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach2.jpg">
    <div>
    ...

</div>
```